# Using MVC Partial View's own model instead of its parent's

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to populate a list box in a partial view, using ASP.NET MVC4.

Can Partial View have its own `@model`, as opposed to taking a model from its parent as described [here](http://mvc4beginner.com/Tutorial/MVC-Partial-Views.html)?

I can populate my dropdown box using a separate AJAX call to another MVC controller (i.e. **not parent** page/url) as discussed [here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=454), but the resulting syntax is a bit more clumsy; furthermore, an additional endpoint is exposed to the outside world.

Answer (score 6):

Yes - you can call partial view with any model you like. There is no requirement that data somehow comes from current model.

```
  @Html.Partial("PartialView1", new MyOtherModel(42))
```